# Why is adding a `reversed` argument to bisect functions considered inefficient?

Tags: python, binary-search

We can use Python's `bisect` module to insert items into an already sorted list efficiently.

But the list has to be sorted in ascending order, which is not always the case.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), the reason is explained:

> > Unlike the sorted() function, it does not make sense for the bisect() functions to have key or reversed arguments because that would lead to an inefficient design (successive calls to bisect functions would not “remember” all of the previous key lookups).

However, when I look at the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py), I can see nothing that seems to be "remember"ing key lookups.

We can just add a `reversed` argument, and swap the `then` part of this condition expression when necessary:

```
if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
else: lo = mid+1
```

Why is this considered inefficient design?

Comment: "I can see nothing that seems to be "remember"ing key lookups." - well of course not. `bisect` doesn't support `key` arguments, so of course you're not going to find any code responsible for remembering keys. Compare that to `sorted`, which computes key values and then reuses them repeatedly for the duration of the sort. It gets to remember key values throughout the entire function call instead of looking them up every time.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're using `bisect`, you're likely to be doing repeated binary searches on the same list. On every call, the keys would need to be recomputed, and the search routine wouldn't get much of an opportunity to reuse the key values.

Comment: @user2357112 What about the `reversed` part of the reason?

Answer (score 2):

What the documentation is saying is that the `bisect` function is intended to be used over and over again on the same list of items.  Instead of using function evaluations to compute the keys on the fly, pre-computing the keys and using those is more efficient, especially since the item list and the key list would be parallel, so the same index can be used for both.

As for reversed, you could get the same effect by reversing the key list:

```
items = [9,7,5,3,1]
keys = list(reversed(items))
index = len(items)-bisect_right(keys,7)
```

But again, this only makes sense if you are going to keep re-using the same keys over and over for multiple searches.

Comment: Adding `reversed` has the same problem?

Comment: The `reversed` function returns a reverse iterator.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that, but IMHO, calling reversed every time before I'm going to do a `insort` is obviously less efficient than adding a `reversed` argument directly.

Comment: @satoru: Yes true.  The authors are suggesting that you create the reversed keys once and re-use them.

Comment: If you're going to reverse the list, it may make sense to also switch which of `bisect_left` or `bisect_right` you're using. Whether this matters likely depends on the application.

Comment: @VaughnCato In that case, maybe I should just write my own `bisect` that support descending lists.

Comment: @user2357112: Good Point, that does make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: @VaughnCato Anyway, I would upvote your answer for explaining the `key function` part.

Comment: @satoru: The bisect algorithm is so simple that they very well could have provided versions of the functions for items in ascending or descending order.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, I'm just asking why not.

Comment: @satoru: I can only guess, but I imagine that since it appears to be designed to look up values in pre-computed tables, that just keeping those tables in the proper order seemed like a simple enough requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some sort of adapter:

```
import bisect

class rvrbisect:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def idxcnv(self, idx): return len(self.data) - idx - 1

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[self.idxcnv(idx)]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self.data[self.idxcnv(idx)] = value

    def __len__(self): return len(self.data)

    def insert(self, idx, value):
        self.data.insert(self.idxcnv(idx) + 1, value)

data = rvrbisect([30, 20, 10])
bisect.insort(data, 25)
bisect.insort(data, 15)
bisect.insort(data, 1)
bisect.insort(data, 190)
print data.data
```